# How to improve the multiple return of my methods in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have some methods in my controller. By example, "search", or "subCategoriesWeb", or "subCategories3D" and so on.

One of these methods looks like this.

```
public function searchSubCategories($request)
{
    // MY CODE HERE

    return view('pages.blog', [
        'articles'         => $articles,
        'orientation'      => $this->getOrientation(),
        'subCategoriesWeb' => $this->getSubCategoriesWeb(),
        'subCategories2d'  => $this->getSubCategories2d(),
        'subCategories3d'  => $this->getSubCategories3d()
    ]);
}
```

And in the end, I am forced to return all my methods, otherwise I have variables defined in my results.

I have to do this for all my methods. for example

```
public function searchCategory($request)
{
    // My code here

    return view('pages.blog', [
        'articles'         => $articles,
        'orientation'      => $this->getOrientation(),
        'subCategoriesWeb' => $this->getSubCategoriesWeb(),
        'subCategories2d'  => $this->getSubCategories2d(),
        'subCategories3d'  => $this->getSubCategories3d()
    ]);
}
```

There's no way to avoid that? Or group them in one place and call them only in one line ?

Thank you very much

Comment: If you are going to use those variables in a lot of places, I really recommend binding them to a view through a view composer instead.

Comment: Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers

Comment: Hey, please update your question here, approve answers so other stackoverflow users can get idea about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method to generate the data and use it.

```
protected function getViewData($articles)
{
    return [
        'articles'         => $articles,
        'orientation'      => $this->getOrientation(),
        'subCategoriesWeb' => $this->getSubCategoriesWeb(),
        'subCategories2d'  => $this->getSubCategories2d(),
        'subCategories3d'  => $this->getSubCategories3d()
    ];
}

public function searchSubCategories($request)
{
    // ...

    return view('pages.blog', $this->getViewData($articles));
}

public function searchCategory($request)
{
    // ...

    return view('pages.blog', $this->getViewData($articles));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use constructor its good practice. Try something like below code.

```
class ControllerName extends Controller
{
    public $variable = 'value';
    public $AnotherVariable = '';

    public function __construct(){
        $this->variable = 'someother value';

        $this->anothervariable = $this->getSubCategories3d();
    }


    public function searchCategory($request)
    {
        return view('pages.blog', [
            'articles'         => $articles,
            'orientation'      => $this->getOrientation(),
            'subCategoriesWeb' => $this->getSubCategoriesWeb(),
            'subCategories2d'  => $this->getSubCategories2d(),
            'subCategories3d'  => $this->anothervariable
        ]);
    }
}
```